# If I travel between two places, can I say that I "experienced" the distance?

Tags: expressions

Suppose I go to place B from place A, and then come back to place A. The distance from place A to place B is 2 kilometers. Is it correct to say that "The distance I experienced is 4 kilometers"? Or "The distance I traveled is 4 kilometers" is a better expression?

Comment: Did you find "The distance I experienced is 4 kilometers" somewhere?

Comment: No. Maybe I coined the phrase from "the delay experienced is ...". But I want to know if there is a similar usage for distance.

Comment: "the delay" is an occurrence you can experience. But *the distance" isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use the verb "experience" when a particular situation (difficulty, problem, loss, etc. affects you or happens to you or you have a particular emotion or feeling (pain, hoppiness, etc.). You can not use "experience" in the sense of travel. The correct sentence is "The distance I travelled is 4 Kilometers".